# How to enable oidc plugin in HashiCorp Vault?

Tags: openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

I'm integrating Gitlab with HashiCorp Vault. For this, the first step is enabling oidc plugin and it's asking SHA checksum of oidc plugin binary file. How to get the SHA checksum of the plugin?

**Sample Payload**

```
{
  "sha256": "d130b9a0fbfddef9709d8ff92e5e6053ccd246b78632fc03b8548457026961e9",
  "command": "oidc-plugin"
}
```

**Sample Request**

```
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request PUT \
    --data @payload.json \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/plugins/catalog/secret/oidc-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I you have get the sha256 checksum from the oidc-plugin binary file you have deployed in `/vault/plugins/<plugin_name>`. Your most logical file should be: `/vault/plugins/oidc-plugin`

So you should just run against your plugin file:

```
$ sha256sum /vault/plugins/oidc-plugin
fcab0f310ee6cd712ddc2f0d110e91111ec4d98d69f55eb5ec8efe7958e7dfc3  /vault/plugins/oidc-plugin
```

And after that execute your PUT request with the checksum you obtained